# MySQL error 1064 table creation

Tags: mysql, syntax-error, mysql-error-1064

This seems a fairly trivial problem but I am having no luck in running the following query:

```
create table if not exists tweet_data (
created_at DATETIME,
user_name VARCHAR(20),
retweet_count INT,
favourite_count INT,
tweet_followers_count INT,
is_retweet BOOLEAN,
tweet_source VARCHAR(256),
user_location VARCHAR(256),
tweet_mentioned_count INT,
tweet_ID VARCHAR(256) NOT NULL,
tweet_text VARCHAR(140),
UNIQUE (tweet_ID) );
```

When I run this I get the following error message:

```
Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual
that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
near '(20),  retweet_count INT,     favourite_count INT,     
tweet_followers_count ' at line 3
```

When I hover over the error tag on line 3 it says:

```
Syntax error : unexpected '(' (opening parenthesis)
```

I'm sure this is a simple fix, any help would be great!

Comment: Should be `user_name VARCHAR(20)` without space between R and (

Comment: isn't it because of space in (20) and VARCHAR in user_name column ?

Comment: Tried this and still getting the same error unfortunately. Will edit to remove the space above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out to be an error with mySQL Workbench

Answer (score 0):

```
create table if not exists  tweet_data (

created_at DATETIME,

user_name VARCHAR (20),

retweet_count INT,

favourite_count INT,

tweet_followers_count INT,

is_retweet BOOLEAN,

tweet_source VARCHAR(256),

user_location VARCHAR(256),

tweet_mentioned_count INT,

tweet_ID VARCHAR(256) NOT NULL,

tweet_text VARCHAR(140),

UNIQUE (tweet_ID) );
```

Man this code is running perfectly.

go to this link and check it your self

http://rextester.com/l/mysql_online_compiler